# Include my own example pictures in filepicker (Intent.ACTION_PICK)

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider, filepicker, storage-access-framework

I'm letting my users pick an image from their file system with `Intent.ACTION_PICK`.
But some users are lazy and don't want to use their own images so I'd like to include a few default/example images that come preinstalled with the app.

Basically I want that the file picker opens a folder of my own app first (from where the user could also navigate to his own files if he wants).
The images that come preinstalled with the app **should not be accessible by other apps**. Only if the file picker is started from my app. So i don't want to just copy them onto the file system.

Is there simple a way to do this? I thought about `ContentProviders` and `DocumentProviders` but I'm not sure if that's what I'm looking for.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

...

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
        Uri uri = resultData.getData();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64634776/open-res-or-assets-folder-with-intent-action-pick-or-intent-action-get-content

Comment: @blackapps The other question is more specific.